# Spring boot, react how to delete entity of specific id?

Tags: reactjs, spring, crud

I'm trying to make a simple CRUD app. I'd like to delete a student of a specific id but I'm getting 400 error.
My controller class in Spring boot looks like this:

```
@DeleteMapping("/student/delete/{id}")
public String deleteById(@PathVariable int id){
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        return "Student deleted";
}
```

In React my delete function looks like this:

```
    const handleDelete = (id) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/student/delete/{id}", {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {"Accept":"application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json"}
    }).then(() => {
        let updatedStudents = [...students].filter(i => i.id !== id);
        setStudents(updatedStudents);
    });
}
```

In my app I'm rendering students from MySQL database, each one with uniqe id. Each student has a delete button with onClick function => handleDelete.
Where can be the problem?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/student/delete/"+id

try above, The problem is you aren't passing the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the id, you missed that

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
fetch("http://localhost:8080/student/delete/"+id, {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {"Accept":"application/json", "Content-Type":"application/json"}
}).then(() => {
    let updatedStudents = [...students].filter(i => i.id !== id);
    setStudents(updatedStudents);
});
}
```